# Socket通信(TCP/Blocking I/O)において、read(recv)実行時にEAGAINが発生するケースについて

Tags: linux, c, centos, socket, tcp

Socket通信(TCP/Blocking I/O)において、以下のようなコードでreadを実行した際に
EAGAINが発生した場合、その原因としてどのようなケースが考えられるのでしょうか？

```
while ((c = read(fileno(din), buf, bufsize)) > 0) {
    // something to do
}
```

EAGAINは主にNon-Blocking I/O時に読み込むデータが無い場合等で発生する認識でしたが、
以下のmanの記載では、Blocking I/O時にもSO_RCVTIMEOが設定されている且つreadが
タイムアウトした場合も発生するように読み取れます。
https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

上記記載の通り、Blocking I/OにおいてもEAGAINが発生するケースはあるのでしょうか。
またあるとすれば、上記の他にどのようなケースが存在するのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

質問に記載の2ケースを想定しておけばよいと思います。(socketの`read`に関する情報は、`recvmsg`のマニュアルを参照するのがよいと思います。そこには、質問に記載の2ケースが述べられています)

[Man page of RECV](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html)

「エラー」節より引用

> **EAGAIN** または **EWOULDBLOCK**
>   ソケットが非停止 (nonblocking) に設定されていて 受信操作が停止するような状況になったか、 受信に時間切れ (timeout) が設定されていて データを受信する前に時間切れになった。
>   POSIX.1-2001 は、この場合にどちらのエラーを返すことも認めており、 これら 2 つの定数が同じ値を持つことも求めていない。
>   したがって、移植性が必要なアプリケーションでは、両方の可能性を 確認すべきである。

Comment: タイムアウトによりEAGAINが返される場合に該当するLinux kernelのソースコードをご存知の方おられませんか？tcp_recvmsg関数を読んでみても、該当する場所が見つけられず。。

Comment: すみません、自己解決しました。sk_wait_event関数内でtimeout変数をwait_woken関数の返り値で上書きしていて、タイムアウト発生時はtcp_recvmsg関数内のtimeoは0になるみたいです。それで!timeoの条件に引っかかって、EAGAINが返るようになっていました。みなさま、ご回答ありがとうございました